# Projectile motion and Quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A particle is projected from ground level so that its height above the ground after $t$ seconds is given by $(20t-5t^2)=m$. After how many seconds is it $15m$ above the ground? I do not know how to plot the graph of this and arrive at the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve $$20t-5t^2=15\\t^2-4t+3=0\\t=1,3$$
When the projectile rises, it will reach 15m at t=1 sec and after some time when  it is descending at t=3 it will again come at a height of 15m.Note that in between exactly at t=2 sec it attains it's maximum height at 20m which is greater than 15m. So projectile reaches 15m twice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Algebraically,  we have $\displaystyle 20t-5t^2=15\iff t^2-4t+3=0\implies t=\cdots$

Observe that there are two positive real values of $t$ (why?)

Comment: The solution is $t=3 seconds$ or $t=1 second$. Why two solutions. How to interpret this

Comment: @AchariSGanesha, As the particle will go up and then ...?